# USB hard disk mount options

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, btrfs

How do I setup mount options for an external USB hard drive?

I have an USB drive formated with BTRFS, each time the USB is plugged the drive is automatically mounted in /media/user/disklabel with defaults options. But I would like to set compression for this disk, and this is achieved with the "-o compress" option in the "mount" command.

How can I change the mount options to the automount service?

I am running Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Connect the disk and let your automounter mount the filesystem
2. Use `lsblk -o UUID,MOUNTPOINT` to find the UUID of the block device the filesystem is on, e.g. `6e642696-3cb4-4d4e-86a6-2fae2b9295cc`.
3. Add a line to your /etc/fstab referencing the UUID and specifying the additional mount option:

   ```
   UUID=6e642696-3cb4-4d4e-86a6-2fae2b9295cc /media/user/backupdrive btrfs noauto,subvol=/,compress=zstd
   ```
4. Unmount and re-mount the drive and check that the options were set using `mount`

Bonus: This also works for filesystems on LUKS-encrypted drives.